# How to check if ListView item is checked or not

Tags: android, android-listview, android-listfragment

I am using `list.setItemChecked(position, true)` to set items as checked in my `ListView`, when clicked. I have found no way however, of seeing if the list item is Checked or not.

The `ListView` item does not have a checkbox/radio and does not use `CheckedTextView`. The `ListView` is set to `CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE`.

**ListView onItemClick Listener**

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
      list.setItemChecked(position, true);
}
```

**Adapter getView**

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rowlayout, parent, false);
    vg = parent;
    TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.label);
    textView.setText(names[position]);
    TextView textView2 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.tvValue);
    textView2.setText(stock[position]);
    return rowView;
}
```

Is there a way to check if the list item is checked or not? For example, in the onItemClick listener doing something like:

```
if(position.isChecked()) {
    //do something
}
```

I have looked all over and cannot seem to come up with anything without adding a checkbox/radio to the layout and changing things around. I appreciate any advice, thanks!

**Edit:**

The title was a little confusing, so just to clarify: The problem isn't that the item isn't clearly selected/unselected, it's that I need to handle the second click on an item that is selected. I was using simple if/else logic to handle this, which worked but causes issues elsewhere in the project, which is why I am wondering if there is some built-in functionality for checking if an item is checked or not.

Comment: why not change the background color on the ones that have been clicked?

Comment: @wyoskibum Yes, I am doing that. The problem isn't that the item isn't clearly selected/unselected, it's that I need to handle the second click on an item that is selected. I was using simple if/else logic to handle this, which worked but causes issues elsewhere in the project, which is why I am wondering if there is some built-in functionality for checking if an item is checked or not.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `list.isItemChecked(position)`.  See the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#isItemChecked(int))

Answer (score 1):

If using Buddy's suggestion of `isItemChecked(position)` won't work for you, below is a potential solution while inside the `listener`.

If I am understanding your desire correctly, you basically want the user to first select an item and then "confirm" the selection with a second click on the item.

If this is the case, I think you're so very close to making a solution. Make a variable outside of the `listener`. In an `OnItemClickListener`, `if` the variable is blank or not equal to the selected `Item`, set the variable to the value of the selected `Item`. `Else`, run the code you wanted to!

Example:

```
myListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClick Listener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parentView, View childView, int position, long id) {
        if (selectedItem == null || selectedItem != position)
            selectedItem = position;
        else {
            //do whatever it is you wanted to do after the second click!
        } //end else
    } //end onItemClick
}); //end onItemClickListener
```

And of course you'll want to clear `selectedItem` every time you bring up the `ListView` again! What do you think?